# Chrome getDisplayMedia stream cropped when sharing non fullscreen application window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, get-display-media

I'm programming a web application that uses webrtc and the build in screen capture api of Chrome with [getDisplayMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia).

In Chrome Browser i am experiencing a strange behaviour when sharing a non fullscreen window.
The window is cropped by about 7 pixels on the left and bottom side in the captured stream.
I noticed this effect when sharing a Mircosoft Excel Window (that is not in fullscreen), as there are plenty elements that are close the the window border. When i maximize the window it is not cropped in the stream.

I'm using Google Chrome Version 89.0.4389.128 (64-bit) and a standard 1080p monitor on Windows 10.

I've been able to replicate this issue in the [getDiplayMedia demo of webrtc experiments](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/getDisplayMedia/), too.
I didn't find an open bug report for Chrome for this issue. Did i miss something? Am i doing something wrong?

Any help or info would be highly appreciated.

Comment: to report a bug in Chrome: https://crbug.com

Comment: Okay, thank you, i did report this as a bug.
I thought this behaviour could be intented and is fixable with some parameter in getDisplayMedia (seems to be not he case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a Google Chrome issue in Windows that is reproducible in stable version 90.0.4430.93 and maybe earlier versions.
For people interested in this issue, follow the bug report [here](http://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1202238).